# Remove an option once it is selected in previous dropdowns

Tags: javascript, php, drop-down-menu, html-select

**I need to remove the selected option in a dropdown that was selected on the previous dropdwon. 
For example the first, second and third dropdown contain A, B, C, D. Once I selected A in dropdown1, it won't appear in both dropdowns 2 and 3. Same thing will happen to both dropdowns 2 and 3.**

But in my code, things are actually like this:

I have several dropdowns populated via loop in PHP.

```
for($y=1; $y<=5; $y++){
echo "<select id='seatplan$x' name='selectSeatplan[]' onChange='callSave($x,$sid)'>";

     echo "<select name='selectSeatplan[]'>";
     echo "<option value=''> ------------ </option>";
          seatplanDdNames($sid);
     echo "</select>";

} //END FOR Y<-5
```

Please note that
* seatplanDdNames($sid) - is a function where names are generated from database and here is how i echo the options from it:

```
function seatplanDdNames($sid) {
     echo "<option value='$studentno' onClick='callSave($x,$sid)'>$name</option>";
}
```

Then the javascript function callSave:

```
function callSave(x,sid){

    var name = 'seatplan' + x;
    name = name.toString();
    var selectBox = document.getElementById(name);
    var strUser = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
    var js = document.createElement('script');
        js.setAttribute('language', 'javascript');
        js.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
        js.setAttribute('src', 'seatplan-getvalues.php?uid='+strUser+'&sid='+sid+'&rtype=CLS&seatno='+x);
    document.body.appendChild(js);

    return false;
    }
```

- The function callSave saves the selected option in a temporary table. Just how the way I like it. The problem is, I have to avoid the redundancy of data provided in the dropdowns.

Any help? Thank you!

Comment: You don't want to use a multiselect? Or checkboxes? Seems more fitting to your needs.

Comment: Hm, what I have here is a function for a seat plan. Each student will be assigned to a seat. And dropdown contains the names of students. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/cUtTM/3/) is pure HTML/JS example. Basically on page load each select has same options. When you select something, on other selects this option hides.

Comment: I need a little more favor, can you please explain the code line per line? I'm having a hard time understanding it. The code doesn't seem to work when there's a value set in each option. :( Thank you!

Comment: I've written some comments http://jsfiddle.net/cUtTM/3/ and I've discovered small bug which is fixed now.

Comment: I can see some issues in your php code. In loop you echo `<select>` tag 2 times. With my JS you should get rid of onClick handlers from options. Heres more bulletproof version: http://jsfiddle.net/cUtTM/5/ . Hope it'll help.

Comment: i only have some advice here. use js cookies to hold your selections and choices. its client side and most efficient. no need for anything complicated. also you may use that to handle CHANGES in selection by user.. ie, take back and redo?

Comment: i think i know what's wrong in my code. the parent node is the div, right? and i have several, like tons of divs in my code. i'm sorry that this reply is too late.

Answer (score 0):

The code from Lolo works very fine but I needed to change `style.dispaly = 'none'` in `o.disabled = true` to avoid a problem with Chrome/Safari in OSX and iOS (element not hidden)

```
if (p == undefined || p == s) {
  o.disabled = false;
}
// option otherwise
else {
  o.disabled = true;
}
```

The behavior is different but the result is the same.